# React - navigation headerRight is not displaying

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this code in my AppNavigation.js:

```
const TodoListsStack = createStackNavigator({
  TodoLists: {
    screen: (props) => <ListsScreen {...props} listType='todo' />,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: 'Todo Lists'
    })
  },
  ...
});
```

This is my screen:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    headerRight: (<Button title='Edit' onPress={() => alert('Switch')} />)
  }
}
```

But, the button will only show if I change this:

```
screen: (props) => <ListsScreen {...props} listType='todo' />
```

To this:

```
screen: ListsScreen
```

I don't mind changing if that's the only/best option, but I need to pass the `listType='todo'` to the component.